# ruby file requires

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to require ruby files just in time?
for example you have a file following classes:

```
require "bar"
class Foo
end

require "bar2"
class Bar
end

require "bar3"
class Bar2
end

require "foo"
class Bar3
end
```

Now I d like to just require the file "bar", if I call something in "foo", which needs stuff out of "bar". But if I require "bar" all the other files will be required also. Is there a way to require files just in time without Runtime Errors? Or is that already the way ruby does it? :)
In my case I have a lot of files, and these files all requires a lot of other stuff and sometimes each other. I want to reduce the load work.. Is there something like "require only if"?

Comment: Hope this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587667/when-to-call-a-require-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

you could implement lazy loading via ruby's `autoload`: http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html

you might want to consider, there are/have been controveries regarding thread-safety.
rails uses it heavily, though.