# Where should I require standard library in Rails convention?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conventions

I want to use standard library `rss` so I required it in initializers' directory.

#### config/initializers/stdlibs.rb

```
require 'rss'
```

But if there is Rails convention for require standard library I'll follow it. Is there a rule for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to call a "require" in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587667/when-to-call-a-require-in-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3587667/8774386).

> If you're concerned about performance then you should require things in the context of where they are needed so that if that portion of your code is not exercised, the library is not loaded.

But

> While this is more efficient in terms of resources, it can make it very difficult to determine the dependencies of your application. Declaring these up-front makes it clear to other people maintaining the software.

So

> You're technically allowed to require anything at any time, late or early, but declaring your requirements up front is better from a design perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Put require in a file where you are using it

```
# some_class.rb
require 'rss'
class SomeClass
  def some_method
    RSS::Parser.parse
  end
end
```

Comment: Where can I find the Rails document for it?